# Small tikz decorated arrow between words inside a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

Effectively, what I want to do is very simple but I am not sure where to go.

I have several nodes of the following form

```
\node (1) at (0,0) {text1 $\rightarrow$ text2};
\node (2) at (0,2) {text2 $\rightarrow$ text3};
\node (3) at (0,4) {text3 $\rightarrow$ text4};
```

I would like to replace the text arrow ($\rightarrow$) with a tikz arrow with a certain decorated arrow head. However, I do not want to specify the start and end of these arrows in each case. Is there a way to say

```
XXXXXXa (arrow from a.right where a is a character of text, to b.left, where b is also a text character) bXXXXXX
```

and further do this within the text for a node? I can then move this node wherever and the arrow stays between my two words of text.

I have been looking at nesting tikzenvironments however this seems to be bad practice so am hoping there is another way.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a macro to do the drawing:

[image]

### Notes:

- The length of the arrow is determined by `\ArrowLength` so that can either be set globally or changed locally with `\renewcommand{\ArrowLength}{<length>}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\ArrowLength}{2.0em}%
\newcommand*{\MyRightArrow}[1][]{%
    \tikz [-stealth, red, yshift=0.5ex, baseline] 
        \draw [-stealth, #1] (0,0) -- (\ArrowLength,0) ;
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) at (0,0) {text1 \MyRightArrow text2};
    \node (2) at (0,1) {text2 \MyRightArrow[blue]text3};
    \node (3) at (0,2) {text3 \MyRightArrow[red, densely dashed]text4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nesting tikz environments though correct?

Comment: I am not sure that using an inline `\tikz` is the equivalent of nesting a `tikzpicture` within a `tikzpicture`.  The cover picture of the `tikz-pgf` manual actually uses `\tikz` within a `\tikzpicture` so I think it is ok.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe a somewhat duplicate question then. I asked separately as was assuming it was nested and there are similar questions about nesting environments etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tikzmarks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, myarrow/.style={->,yshift=.3em,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt}]

     \node (1) at (0,0) {text1\tikzmark{t1} \phantom{$\rightarrow$} \tikzmark{t2}text2};
     \draw[myarrow](pic cs:t1)--(pic cs:t2);

     \node (2) at (0,2) {text3\tikzmark{t3} \phantom{$\rightarrow$} \tikzmark{t4}text4};
     \draw[myarrow](pic cs:t3)--(pic cs:t4);

     \node (3) at (0,4) {text5 $\rightarrow$ text6};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It needs two runs to draw the arrows in the correct positions. You can further tweak the style of the arrow (`myarrow` in the mwe) if you want to make it exactly the same as `$\rightarrow$`. I used `phantom`s to keep the distance between text.

### tcolorbox solution

Another possibility is to load `tcolorbox` and draw an invisible box around the text you want to connect inside a node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbox{mybox}[1]{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    size=minimal,
    on line,
    opacityback=0,
    opacityframe=0,
    remember as=#1,
}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,myarrow/.style={->,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt}]

    \node (1) at (0,0) {\mybox{b1}{text1} \phantom{$\rightarrow$} \mybox{b2}{text2}};
    \draw[myarrow](b1.east)--(b2.west);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When you have the text boxed you can connect the boxes using standard node anchors (north, south, etc.) as if it were a node inside a node. This spare you from adjusting the xshift of the arrow, since you can anchor it to `box.east`. It still needs two compilations and the final result is basically the same as before.

Comment: I feel \tikz is an easier answer. \tikzmarks seem very useful though, thanks, I'll have to check them out.