# How to use \tikz\pic in \caption and "normal" Latex-text-environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, tikz-pic

As an advancement to [How to use a \pic in a node's text area {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311587/how-to-use-a-pic-in-a-nodes-text-area/311639#311639). What to do or avoid to let work the pic "lightning" in a caption and normal latex text?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}%offers nice setstretch
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,arrows.meta,calc}

%ever last package
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]

\tikzset{%
pics/lightning/.style n args={3}{code={%
   \draw[arrows={-Stealth[scale=#3]}] (#1) --
      ($(#1)!.4!(#2) + (.1,-.1)$) --
      ($(#1)!.4!(#2) + (-.1,.1)$) --
      (#2);
      }},
}%end tikzset

\begin{tikzpicture}%
[%
 every node/.style={%
    inner sep=0pt},%
]%
\begin{scope}[ text height=1.0em, text depth=.25em,]

   \node (advbo)                       {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
   \node (so)    [left =.9mm of advbo] {\textit{Substantiv}};
   \node (ao)    [left =.9mm of so]    {\textit{Artikel}};
   \node (ko)    [left =.9mm of ao]    {\textit{Komparativ}};

   \node (l)     [below= of ko]        {Lieber};
   \node (e1)    [below= of ao]        {einen};
   \node (s)     [below= of so]        {Spatz};
   \node (i)     [below= of advbo]     {in der Hand,};

   \node (a)     [below=.3mm of l]     {als};
   \node (e2)    [below=.3mm of e1]    {eine};
   \node (t)     [below=.3mm of s]     {Taube};
   \node (ad)    [below=.3mm of i]     {auf dem Dach.};

   \node (ku)    [below= of a]         {\textit{Konjunktion}};
   \node (au)    [below= of e2]        {\textit{Artikel}};
   \node (su)    [below= of t]         {\textit{Substantiv}};
   \node (advbu) [below= of ad]        {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
\end{scope}

   \pic [red] {lightning={ko}{l}{1.2}};
   \pic [red, rotate=180]{lightning={ku}{a}{1.2}};

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (ao)    to (e1);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (au)    to (e2);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (so)    to (s);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (su)    to (t);

   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbo) to (i);
   \draw[->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5] (advbu) to (ad);

   \draw[xshift=2.75cm,yshift=-1.8cm]
      node[right,text width=4cm,rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em]%information text]
      {
         Parallelismus, der nicht ganz konsequent durchgestaltet ist, denn hier
         (\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
         stimmen die Wortarten nicht "uberein.
         \smallskip

         \setstretch{0.1}

         {\tiny{Der \textit{Komparativ} entstammt der Wortart \textit{Adjektiv}, der  parallele Satzteil entstammt der Wortart \textit{Konjunktion}}}.

         \setstretch{1.0}
      };

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Parallelismus mit einer nicht
%uncommented raises undefinde control sequence
%(\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung}\label{paraIincomplete}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

Parallelismus mit einer nicht
%DOESNT WOK TOO, same as above
%(\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, without `\pic` for zig-zag arrow, different  node positioning and without use of the `setspace` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,chains,positioning}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style = {%
    to path={ -- ($(\tikztostart)!.48!-7:(\tikztotarget)$) --
                 ($(\tikztostart)!.40!+7:(\tikztotarget)$) -- (\tikztotarget)
             \tikztonodes},sharp corners}
            }
   %ever last package
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

    \begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
     node distance = 11mm and 0mm,
       start chain = going below,
 every node/.style = {minimum height=1em, text depth=.25em, 
                      align=center, on chain},
                    ]
% first
\node (ko)  {\textit{Komparativ}};
\node (i)   {Lieber\\ als};
\node (ku)  {\textit{Konjunktion}};
% second
\node (ao)  [right= of ko]   
            {\textit{Artikel}};
\node (s)   {einen\\eine};
\node (au)  {\textit{Artikel}};
% third
\node (so)  [right= of ao]  
            {\textit{Substantiv}};
\node (e1)  {Spatz\\Taube};
\node (su)  {\textit{Substantiv}};
% fourth
\node (advbo) [right= of so] 
                {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
\node (l)       {in der Hand,\\auf the Dach.};
\node (advbu)   {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
% arrows
\draw[red,thick,-stealth'] 
            (ko) edge[zigzag]  (i)
            (ku)  to [zigzag]  (i);
\draw[-stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5]
    (ao)    edge (s)    (au)    edge    (s)     
    (so)    edge (e1)   (su)    edge    (e1)
    (advbo) edge (l)    (advbu)  to     (l);
% legend
\node[rounded corners=1em, fill=red!10,
     text width=4cm, text depth={},
     inner sep=1em, font=\scriptsize, align=justify,
     right=2mm of advbu.east |- l]%information text
  { {\normalsize
     Parallelismus, der nicht ganz konsequent durchgestaltet ist, denn hier
    (\tikz[baseline=1pt,yscale=0.5]\draw[red,-stealth'] (0,4ex) to [zigzag] (0,0);)
     stimmen die Wortarten nicht "uberein.
     }\medskip

    Der \textit{Komparativ} entstammt der Wortart \textit{Adjektiv}, der  parallele Satzteil entstammt der Wortart \textit{Konjunktion}.
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Parallelismus mit einer nicht passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung]
        {Parallelismus mit einer nicht
        (\tikz[baseline=1pt,yscale=0.5]\draw[red,-stealth'] (0,4ex) to [zigzag] (0,0);)        passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung}
\label{paraIincomplete}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @torbj%c3%b8rn-t thank you for the hint to change rounded corners

Comment: great answer for TMTOWTDI. I'm too slow to answer myself before you can transfer the "information text" in block mode (centered version less nice)? Fantastic reaction!

Comment: last comment for you

Comment: "at" Zarko vanishes every time?

Comment: @gizeh, seems that your comments above is intended to Torbjørn T.
answer, not mine ... however, just now I slightly change looks of "information" node on the right side.

Comment: you have great experience, cool use of many syntactic fearures, one package (setspave) less, and the "lightning" much better built

Answer (score 2):

The one in the caption doesn't work because of some issues caused by it also being added to the list of figures. Easy workaround is to also provide the optional argument to caption, which is an alternative caption that is placed in the LoF:

```
\caption[Parallelismus mit einer nicht passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung]{Parallelismus mit einer nicht
%uncommented raises undefinde control sequence
(\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung}
```

The one in the text afterwords doesn't work because you've defined that `pic` inside the `figure` environment (which forms a group), and that definition will then only be known in that environment. Move the `\tikzset` to the preamble instead.

Also note that

- It doesn't make sense to have a `figure` environment *inside* a `center` environment. The `figure` is a floating environment, so it will likely move away and give you some unwanted vertical space in your document. If you want to center what's inside the `figure`, add `\centering` right after `\begin{figure}`.
- `\tiny` is used as `\tiny small text` or `{\tiny small text\par}`, not as `\tiny{small text}` -- it is not a macro that takes an argument, the way e.g. `\textit` is. (It still mostly works, but the braces around `small text` doesn't do anything useful I think.

  Further, whenever using it as `{\tiny text}`,  you need to remember to add a paragraph break before the closing brace, i.e. an empty line or `{\tiny text\par}`.  If you don't do this the baselineskip (distance from base of one line to the next) will not change. This is the reason for the wide line spacing you hacked your way around with the `\setstretch`. The same problem is there in Zarko's answer, the `\normalsize` text has a baselineskip that is too small, add a `\par` before the closing brace and see it change.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,arrows.meta,calc}

%ever last package
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\tikzset{%
pics/lightning/.style n args={3}{code={%
   \draw[arrows={-Stealth[scale=#3]}] (#1) --
      ($(#1)!.4!(#2) + (.1,-.1)$) --
      ($(#1)!.4!(#2) + (-.1,.1)$) --
      (#2);
      }},
  redarrow/.style={->,>=stealth', very thick, red, opacity=.5}}%end tikzset
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]



\begin{tikzpicture}%
[%
 every node/.style={%
    inner sep=0pt},%
]%
\begin{scope}[ text height=1.0em, text depth=.25em,]

   \node (advbo)                       {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
   \node (so)    [left =.9mm of advbo] {\textit{Substantiv}};
   \node (ao)    [left =.9mm of so]    {\textit{Artikel}};
   \node (ko)    [left =.9mm of ao]    {\textit{Komparativ}};

   \node (l)     [below= of ko]        {Lieber};
   \node (e1)    [below= of ao]        {einen};
   \node (s)     [below= of so]        {Spatz};
   \node (i)     [below= of advbo]     {in der Hand,};

   \node (a)     [below=.3mm of l]     {als};
   \node (e2)    [below=.3mm of e1]    {eine};
   \node (t)     [below=.3mm of s]     {Taube};
   \node (ad)    [below=.3mm of i]     {auf dem Dach.};

   \node (ku)    [below= of a]         {\textit{Konjunktion}};
   \node (au)    [below= of e2]        {\textit{Artikel}};
   \node (su)    [below= of t]         {\textit{Substantiv}};
   \node (advbu) [below= of ad]        {\textit{Adverbiale Bestimmung}};
\end{scope}

   \pic [red] {lightning={ko}{l}{1.2}};
   \pic [red, rotate=180]{lightning={ku}{a}{1.2}};

   \draw[redarrow] (ao)    to (e1);
   \draw[redarrow] (au)    to (e2);

   \draw[redarrow] (so)    to (s);
   \draw[redarrow] (su)    to (t);

   \draw[redarrow] (advbo) to (i);
   \draw[redarrow] (advbu) to (ad);

   \draw[xshift=2.75cm,yshift=-1.8cm]
      node[right,text width=4cm,rounded corners,fill=red!10,inner sep=1em]%information text]
      {
         Parallelismus, der nicht ganz konsequent durchgestaltet ist, denn hier
         (\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
         stimmen die Wortarten nicht "uberein.
         \smallskip


         \tiny Der \textit{Komparativ} entstammt der Wortart \textit{Adjektiv}, der  parallele Satzteil entstammt der Wortart \textit{Konjunktion}. \par % alternatively add emtpy line before };
      };

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Parallelismus mit einer nicht passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung]{Parallelismus mit einer nicht
(\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung}\label{paraIincomplete}
\end{figure}


Parallelismus mit einer nicht
(\tikz[baseline=1pt]\pic [red] {lightning={0pt,9pt}{0pt,-2pt}{.7}};)
passenden Wortarten-Parallelisierung
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: T., thanks for your great advice, solution and shared knowhow. I am astonished about the different appearance (rounded corners in tikz node, sharp and a bit greater in the Latex environment). A better look I hope will be found by changing the 3 params of "lightning".

Comment: @gizeh Oh, didn't notice that. Seems it inherits the `rounded corners` setting from the node options.

Comment: @gizeh To remove the rounded corners in the `\node`, add `rounded corners=0` to the options of the `\draw` in the `pic`.

Comment: @gizeh I realized I had forgotten one crucial thing about `\tiny`, see my updated answer.